# UISearchBars. Copy Array always equals to Nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

```
 - (void)searchTableList {
        NSString *searchString = searchBar.text;
        NSString *str=[[stories valueForKeyPath:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@"@"];
        NSLog(@"desired string:%@",str);
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
```

//Never attempt to use compare with an array of dictionaries have to extract strings first first

```
        for (NSString *tempStr in stories) {
            NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
                [filteredContentList addObject:tempStr];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you missed to ask your question? What is your question and where is the bug?

Comment: Do you want us to read the question "UISearchbar headaches" and find ourselves the question and clear the bug?

Comment: nope i edited my question. The question is why the second array FilteredContentList is equal to nil, even if i make a copy of "stories" the initial Array, with FilteredContentList.

Comment: i don't see in viewDidLoad, the alloc init of the FilteredContentList, or at least when copied

Comment: Yes it's because i init it in the method that start the xml parsing, but even if i put the init in viewDidLoad i still got the exception because the array is equal to nil.

Comment: Nothing in your code above deallocates filteredContentList. You either not initializing it the right way or deallocate it somewhere else.

Comment: in the method textDidChange at the bottom of the question, can't be [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];  interpreted as a dealloc of the filteredContentList Array  ?

Comment: Nope, it will, by design, decreace reference counter on each object previously contained in the array, which may lead to deallocation of each of those objects, but not the array itself. Are you using __weak or autorelease or custom autorelease pools, maybe? Do other objects have access to your filteredContentList? How is filteredContentList being initialized?

Comment: i'am using autorelease and no other object have access to filteredContentList. I initialized it in the ViewDidLoad like this : filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: I think i found the problem, in searchTabeList "stories" is a NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries maybe it is not supported compare :8 ?

Comment: Did it !!! the problem was the "stories" array wich wasn't supported by the comparison in the searchTableList but wasn't also given me any warning. i had to extract my strings from the array put them in another array than sort. also relying on tableViewParameter is way much better. Thank you Mr Birukaze for your time and concern.

Comment: Glad you've figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `filteredContentList` is never allocated in your code above, so it will always point to nil. Add smth like `filteredContentList = [NSMutableArray array]` in `viewDidLoad`.
Secondary, you rely on `isSearching` `boolean` flag to detect wether your are dealing with search results table view or general `table view` of you controller. This is, IMHO, bad practice. 
You should rely on tableView parameter, which is being passed to every method of table views delegates (in your case -- your `UITableViewController`). Set tags or compare tableView parameter to `self.tableView`.
Last thing -- you do not need to call `reloadData` at `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Okay gotcha, i will make all this changes.

Comment: did you meant to say [NSMutableArray array]